# Segmentation fault with unknown reason (C)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I was trying to solve my data structure homework, and I used doubly linked list in my code. But when I used it to create a new node and return to main, I got a segmentation fault.

my function(append) is like:

```
void append(struct Node** RailHead[], int new_data, int r){
/* 1. allocate node */
printf("1.\n");
struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
struct Node* last = RailHead[r]; /* used in step 5*/

/* 2. put in the data  */
new_node->data = new_data;

/* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so
      make next of it as NULL*/
new_node->next = NULL;

/* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new
      node as head */
if (RailHead[r] == NULL){
    new_node-> prev = NULL;
    RailHead[r] = new_node;
    return;
}

/* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
while (last->next != NULL)
    last = last->next;

/* 6. Change the next of last node */
last->next = new_node;

/* 7. Make last node as previous of new node */
new_node-> prev = last;
return;
}
```

RailHead is the pointer array that I adopted to store the different head reference of doubly linked lists, and r is the assigned rail (by input) to decide which rail should append new data.

I would like to understand what's going on with my code. If anyone can help, I will be really appreciate about it! Thank you!

Comment: Now seems to be the perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes, and how to use it to locate where in your code the crash happens and then examine variables and their values.

Comment: `struct Node* last = RailHead[r];` should not even compile, right side has type `struct Node **`, left side `struct Node*`. Similar problem with `RailHead[r] = new_node;`.

Comment: So if I try change my declaration as struct Node* RailHead[10], it might help to solve the inconsistent problem? Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`  1) the return type, in C, is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointers.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful..

Comment: regarding: `void append(struct Node** RailHead[],`  if this is accessing a linked list, then the trailing `[]` is an error.  Since this is NOT a pointer to an array,  there are several  other errors in the posted code from this initial error